# React Router Dom Issue - localhost:3000/products to localhost:3000/products/2 is working fine but when I refresh page then I get some error in console

Tags: reactjs, url, react-redux, react-router-dom

I have an Index.js where I am getting data via async function and sending data to ProductList Component and from ProductList Component I am sending an id onclick of product Image and then I get Product Detail Page a Single Product. I get Single Product with no issues but when I refresh then I get an error in console saying - ***Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')*** I have used REDUX.

INDEX.JS

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
// import PageNotFound from "../other/page-not-found/PageNotFound";
import ProductList from "./product-list/ProductList";
import ProductFilter from "./product-filter/ProductFilter";
import ProductSearch from "./product-search/ProductSearch";
import Cart from "./cart/Cart";
// import MobileFilterModal from "./mobile-filter-modal/MobileFilterModal";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { setProductListData } from "../../redux/actions/product-list-actions/ProductListActions";
import Loading from "../other/loading/Loading";
import Skeleton from "../other/skeletons/Skeleton";
// import PageNotFound from "../other/page-not-found/PageNotFound";

const Index = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const filters = useSelector(
    (state) => state.productList.productListData.filters
  );
  const products = useSelector(
    (state) => state.productList.productListData.products
  );
  // console.log(products);

  useEffect(() => {
    getProductsData();
  }, []);

  const getProductsData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/productListing");
      const data = await response.json();
      if (data) {
        setIsLoading(false);
        dispatch(setProductListData(data));
      } else {
        setIsLoading(true);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // if (isLoading) {
  //   return <Loading loadingProductList={"products"} />;
  // }

  return (
    <>
      {filters && products && (
        <main>
          <div className="dvMain">
            <div className="container-fluid">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="dvFilters col-lg-3 col-xl-2 d-none d-lg-block text-right">
                  <div className="sticky-top" style={{ top: "90px" }}>
                    {isLoading
                      ? filters.map((filter) => {
                          return (
                            <Skeleton key={filter.id} filterId={filter.id} />
                          );
                        })
                      : filters &&
                        filters.map((filter) => {
                          return <ProductFilter key={filter.id} {...filter} />;
                        })}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="dvProducts col-lg-6 col-xl-8">
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="dvSearch col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-lg-12 mb-3">
                      {isLoading ? (
                        <Skeleton productSearch={"productSearch"} />
                      ) : (
                        <ProductSearch />
                      )}
                    </div>
                    <div className="dvFilterMobile col-sm-3 col-md-2 d-lg-none text-center text-sm-right mb-3">
                      <a
                        href=""
                        className="btn bg-light w-100"
                        data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target="#mobileFiltersModal"
                      >
                        <i className="fa fa-filter"></i>Filter
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="row">
                    {isLoading
                      ? products.map((product) => {
                          return (
                            <Skeleton key={product.id} productId={product.id} />
                          );
                        })
                      : products &&
                        products.map((product) => {
                          return <ProductList key={product.id} {...product} />;
                        })}
                  </div>
                </div>
                {isLoading ? <Skeleton cart={"cart"} /> : <Cart />}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

PRODUCTLIST.JS

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./productlist.css";

const ProductList = ({ id, img, pack, price, size, heading, description }) => {
  // console.log(id, img, pack, price, size, heading, description);
  // console.log(id, img, pack, price, size, heading, description);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6 col-xl-3 mb-4">
        <div className="border border-light shadow-sm p-1 h-100">
          <div className="image">
            <p className="packs">pack of 5</p>
            <div className="bg-light text-center pt-2 pb-2 mb-1">
              <Link className="d-inline-block" to={`/${id}`}>
                <img src={img} className="img-fluid" alt={heading} />
              </Link>
            </div>
            <h5 className="heading-5 text-center">{heading}</h5>
          </div>
          <div className="description d-flex justify-content-between mb-1">
            <div className="paragraph">
              <p>{size}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="paragraph mr-2">
              <span>
                <i className="fa fa-inr"></i>
                <span>{price}</span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="addBtn text-center">
            <button className="btn btn-white w-100" href="detail.html">
              Add to Bag
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductList;
```

PRODUCTDETAIL.JS

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Cart from "../cart/Cart";
import "./productdetail.css";
import Loading from "../../other/loading/Loading";
import PageNotFound from "../../other/page-not-found/PageNotFound";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { setSelectedProduct } from "../../../redux/actions/product-detail-actions/ProductDetailActions";

const ProductDetail = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const { id } = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const products = useSelector(
    (state) => state.productList.productListData.products
  );
  const singleProduct = useSelector(
    (state) => state.singleProduct.singleProduct
  );

  // console.log(id);
  // console.log(products);
  // console.log(singleProduct);

  useEffect(() => {
    getProductId();
  }, []);

  const getProductId = () => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    // localStorage.setItem("setProducts", JSON.stringify(products));
    // let getProducts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("setProducts"));
    products ? setIsLoading(false) : setIsLoading(true);
    let singleProduct = [];
    singleProduct = products.filter((product) => {
      return product.id === parseInt(id);
    });
    // console.log(singleProduct);
    dispatch(setSelectedProduct(singleProduct));
  };

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Loading loadingProductDetail={"product detail"} />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {singleProduct && (
        <main>
          <div className="dvMain">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row">
                {singleProduct ? (
                  singleProduct.map((product) => {
                    const {
                      id,
                      img,
                      heading,
                      description,
                      category,
                      price,
                      size,
                    } = product;
                    return (
                      <div key={id} className="col-lg-9">
                        <div className="row">
                          <div className="dvProducts col-12">
                            <div className="row">
                              <div className="dvBack col-12">
                                <Link
                                  to="/products"
                                  className="mb-1 d-inline-block"
                                >
                                  <i className="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                                  <span> Back</span>
                                </Link>
                              </div>
                              <div className="col-12">
                                <div className="row">
                                  <div className="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 mb-3">
                                    <div className="border border-light shadow-sm p-1 h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                                      <div className="bg-light text-center h-100">
                                        <a className="d-inline-block h-100">
                                          <img
                                            src={img}
                                            className="img-fluid"
                                            alt={heading}
                                          />
                                        </a>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div className="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-8 d-flex mb-3 mb-xl-0">
                                    <div className="m-md-auto">
                                      <div>
                                        <h2 className="heading-2">{heading}</h2>
                                      </div>
                                      <div className="mb-2">
                                        <i className="fa fa-star text-warning d-inline-block"></i>
                                        <i className="fa fa-star text-warning d-inline-block"></i>
                                        <i className="fa fa-star text-warning d-inline-block"></i>
                                        <i className="fa fa-star-o text-warning d-inline-block"></i>
                                        <i className="fa fa-star-o text-warning d-inline-block"></i>
                                      </div>
                                      <div className="mb-3">
                                        <p className="paragraph">
                                          {description}
                                        </p>
                                      </div>
                                      <div className="d-flex mb-3">
                                        <div className="mr-2">
                                          <h5 className="heading-5 d-inline-block mb-1 mr-1">
                                            Size:
                                          </h5>
                                          <span className="paragraph d-inline-block">
                                            {size}
                                          </span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="mr-2 ml-2">
                                          <h5 className="heading-5 d-inline-block mb-1 mr-1">
                                            Category:
                                          </h5>
                                          <span className="paragraph d-inline-block">
                                            {category}
                                          </span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="ml-2">
                                          <h5 className="heading-5 d-inline-block mb-1 mr-1">
                                            Price:
                                          </h5>
                                          <span className="paragraph d-inline-block">
                                            <i className="fa fa-inr"></i>
                                            <span className="d-inline-block">
                                              {price}.00
                                            </span>
                                          </span>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div>
                                        <button
                                          className="btn btn-black"
                                          href="/-"
                                        >
                                          Add to Bag
                                        </button>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div className="dvTabs col-12 mt-4">
                            <div className="row">
                              <div className="col-12">
                                <div className="row">
                                  <div className="col-12">
                                    <ul
                                      className="nav nav-tabs"
                                      id="myTab"
                                      role="tablist"
                                    >
                                      <li className="nav-item">
                                        <a
                                          className="heading-5 nav-link active"
                                          id="description-tab"
                                          data-toggle="tab"
                                          href="#description"
                                          role="tab"
                                          aria-controls="description"
                                          aria-selected="true"
                                        >
                                          Description
                                        </a>
                                      </li>
                                    </ul>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div
                                  className="dvTabsContent tab-content row"
                                  id="myTabContent"
                                >
                                  <div
                                    className="tab-pane fade show active py-3 col-12"
                                    id="description"
                                    role="tabpanel"
                                    aria-labelledby="description-tab"
                                  >
                                    <div className="row">
                                      <div className="col-12">
                                        <div className="table-responsive">
                                          <table className="table table-striped table-bordered">
                                            <thead>
                                              <tr>
                                                <th
                                                  className="heading-5"
                                                  scope="col"
                                                >
                                                  Details
                                                </th>
                                                <th
                                                  className="heading-5"
                                                  scope="col"
                                                >
                                                  Weight
                                                </th>
                                                <th
                                                  className="heading-5"
                                                  scope="col"
                                                >
                                                  1Glass 250ml
                                                </th>
                                              </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td>Amount per serving</td>
                                                <td>250ml</td>
                                                <td></td>
                                              </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                          </table>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    );
                  })
                ) : (
                  <PageNotFound />
                )}
                <Cart id={id} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductDetail;
```

APP.JS

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Homepage from "./containers/home-page/index";
import Header from "./containers/header/Header";
import Footer from "./containers/footer/Footer";
// import ProductListing from "./containers/products/product-list/ProductList";
import ProductDetail from "./containers/products/product-detail/ProductDetail";
import PageNotFound from "./containers/other/page-not-found/PageNotFound";
import Account from "./containers/account/index";
import Checkout from "./containers/checkout/Index";
import LoginModal from "./containers/auth/modal/login-modal/LoginModal";
import SignupModal from "./containers/auth/modal/signup-modal/SignupModal";
import MobileCartModal from "./containers/products/mobile-cart-modal/MobileCartModal";
import Index from "./containers/products";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <main>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Homepage} />
            <Route path="/products" component={Index} />
            <Route path="/:id" children={<ProductDetail />} />
            <Route path="/checkout" component={Checkout} />
            <Route path="/account" component={Account} />
            <Route path="*" component={PageNotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </main>
        <Footer />
        <LoginModal />
        <SignupModal />
        <MobileCartModal />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

PRODUCTDETAILACTIONS.JS

```
export const setSelectedProduct = (product) => {
  return {
    type: "SET_SELECTED_PRODUCT",
    payload: product,
  };
};
```

PRODUCTDETAILREDUCER.JS

```
const initialState = {
  singleProduct: [],
};

export const productDetailReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_SELECTED_PRODUCT":
      return {
        ...state,
        singleProduct: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

REDUCER INDEX.JS

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { aboutUsReducer } from "./aboutus-reducers/AboutUsReducers";
import { footerReducer } from "./footer-reducers/FooterReducer";
import { headerReducer } from "./header-reducers/headerReducer";
import { mainSliderReducer } from "./homepage-reducers/mainSliderReducer";
import { youtubeReducer } from "./homepage-reducers/YoutubeReducer";
import { productDetailReducer } from "./product-detail/ProductDetailReducer";
import { productListReducer } from "./product-list-reducers/ProductListReducer";
import { productSliderData } from "./productslider-reducers/ProductSliderReducer";
import { teamReducer } from "./team-reducers/TeamReducers";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  header: headerReducer,
  mainSlider: mainSliderReducer,
  youtube: youtubeReducer,
  aboutUs: aboutUsReducer,
  productSlider: productSliderData,
  team: teamReducer,
  footer: footerReducer,
  productList: productListReducer,
  singleProduct: productDetailReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

STORE.JS

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./reducers/index";

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  {},
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

export default store;
```

PRODUCTLISTACTIONS.JS

```
export const setProductListData = (data) => {
  return {
    type: "SET_PRODUCT_LIST_DATA",
    payload: data,
  };
};
```

PRODUCTLISTREDUCER.JS

```
const initialState = {
  productListData: {},
};

export const productListReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_PRODUCT_LIST_DATA":
      return {
        ...state,
        productListData: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

DB.JSON
I am fetching productListing from json file which look like this
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I found this solution. I fetched products through async function instead of getting products back from useSelector. Please check ProductDetail Component below.

PRODUCTDETAIL.JS

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Cart from "../cart/Cart";
import "./productdetail.css";
import Loading from "../../other/loading/Loading";
import PageNotFound from "../../other/page-not-found/PageNotFound";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { setSelectedProduct } from "../../../redux/actions/product-detail-actions/ProductDetailActions";

const ProductDetail = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const { id } = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const singleProduct = useSelector(
    (state) => state.singleProduct.singleProduct
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    getProductListingData();
  }, []);

  const getProductListingData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/productListing");
      const data = await response.json();
      if (data) {
        setLoading(false);
        getProductID(data.products);
      } else {
        // setProducts("PRODUCT LISTING DATA NOT FOUND");
        setLoading(true);
        console.log("PRODUCT LISTING DATA NOT FOUND");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const getProductID = (products) => {
    window.scroll(0, 0);
    let singleProduct = [];
    singleProduct = products.filter((item) => {
      return item.id === parseInt(id);
    });
    dispatch(setSelectedProduct(singleProduct));
  };

  if (loading) {
    return <Loading loadingProductDetail="Loading Product Details" />;
  }

  console.log(id);
  console.log(singleProduct);

  return (
    <>
      <main>
        <div className="dvMain">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              {singleProduct.length > 0 &&
                singleProduct.map((product) => {
                  const {
                    id,
                    img,
                    heading,
                    description,
                    pack,
                    price,
                    size,
                    category,
                    detailsTable,
                  } = product;
                  return (
                    <div key={id} className="col-lg-9">
                      <div className="row">
                        <div key={id} className="dvProducts col-12">
                          <div className="row">
                            <div className="dvBack col-12">
                              <Link
                                to="/products"
                                className="mb-1 d-inline-block"
                              >
                                <i className="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                                <span> Back</span>
                              </Link>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-12">
                              <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 mb-3">
                                  <div className="border border-light shadow-sm p-1 h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                                    <div className="bg-light text-center h-100">
                                      <a className="d-inline-block h-100">
                                        <img
                                          src={img}
                                          className="img-fluid"
                                          alt={heading}
                                        />
                                      </a>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-8 d-flex mb-3 mb-xl-0">
                                  <div className="m-md-auto">
                                    <div>
                                      <h2 className="heading-2">{heading}</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="mb-2">
                                      <i className="fa fa-star text-warning d-inline-block"></i>
                                      <i className="fa fa-star text-warning d-inline-block"></i>
                                      <i className="fa fa-star text-warning d-inline-block"></i>
                                      <i className="fa fa-star-o text-warning d-inline-block"></i>
                                      <i className="fa fa-star-o text-warning d-inline-block"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="mb-3">
                                      <p className="paragraph">{description}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="d-flex mb-3">
                                      <div className="mr-2">
                                        <h5 className="heading-5 d-inline-block mb-1 mr-1">
                                          Pack:
                                        </h5>
                                        <span className="paragraph d-inline-block">
                                          {pack}
                                        </span>
                                      </div>
                                      <div className="mr-2">
                                        <h5 className="heading-5 d-inline-block mb-1 mr-1">
                                          Size:
                                        </h5>
                                        <span className="paragraph d-inline-block">
                                          {size}
                                        </span>
                                      </div>
                                      <div className="mr-2 ml-2">
                                        <h5 className="heading-5 d-inline-block mb-1 mr-1">
                                          Category:
                                        </h5>
                                        <span className="paragraph d-inline-block">
                                          {category}
                                        </span>
                                      </div>
                                      <div className="ml-2">
                                        <h5 className="heading-5 d-inline-block mb-1 mr-1">
                                          Price:
                                        </h5>
                                        <span className="paragraph d-inline-block">
                                          <i className="fa fa-inr"></i>
                                          <span className="d-inline-block">
                                            {price}.00
                                          </span>
                                        </span>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                      <button
                                        className="btn btn-black"
                                        href="/-"
                                      >
                                        Add to Bag
                                      </button>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="dvTabs col-12 mt-4">
                          <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-12">
                              <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-12">
                                  <ul
                                    className="nav nav-tabs"
                                    id="myTab"
                                    role="tablist"
                                  >
                                    <li className="nav-item">
                                      <a
                                        className="heading-5 nav-link active"
                                        id="description-tab"
                                        data-toggle="tab"
                                        href="#description"
                                        role="tab"
                                        aria-controls="description"
                                        aria-selected="true"
                                      >
                                        Description
                                      </a>
                                    </li>
                                  </ul>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div
                                className="dvTabsContent tab-content row"
                                id="myTabContent"
                              >
                                <div
                                  className="tab-pane fade show active py-3 col-12"
                                  id="description"
                                  role="tabpanel"
                                  aria-labelledby="description-tab"
                                >
                                  <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col-12">
                                      <div className="table-responsive">
                                        <table className="table table-striped table-bordered">
                                          <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                              <th
                                                className="heading-5"
                                                scope="col"
                                              >
                                                Details
                                              </th>
                                              <th
                                                className="heading-5"
                                                scope="col"
                                              >
                                                Weight
                                              </th>
                                              <th
                                                className="heading-5"
                                                scope="col"
                                              >
                                                1Glass 250ml
                                              </th>
                                            </tr>
                                          </thead>
                                          <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td>Amount per serving</td>
                                              <td>250ml</td>
                                              <td></td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              <Cart id={id} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductDetail;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the `ProductDetails` component is missing a dependency on the `id` route param to select the correct products *to filter*, and I am assuming that since the index file is fetching and populating the store each time it mounts that perhaps the initial products state is null, undefined, or some other non-array value that is missing the `filter` method.

Add the missing `id` route param to the `useEffect` hook's dependency array so products are fetched when the route changes.

```
const { id } = useParams();

...

useEffect(() => {
  getProductId(id);
}, [id]);
```

Since it appears that `products` is potentially undefined, i.e. falsey, you should account for then when attempting to filter the array. Provide a fallback empty array to filter from if `products` is falsey.

```
const getProductId = (id) => {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  products ? setIsLoading(false) : setIsLoading(true);

  const singleProduct = (products || []).filter((product) => {
    return product.id === parseInt(id);
  });

  dispatch(setSelectedProduct(singleProduct));
};
```

You didn't include any of your Redux code (*i.e. actions/reducers/store configuration*) but a suggestion is to always provide a consistent state invariant. For example, ***always*** returning an array of `products` and using the array length and some "isLoading" state to determine when it's safe to filter the state. At a minimum, if it's guaranteed that `products` is ***always*** an array then all array methods will always work as expected, regardless of where the app is in its lifecycle and loading data/state.

Comment: Thanks Drew, I added Redux code, please check if you miss something.

Comment: Hi @AmeyS, I take my answer hadn't resolved your question/issue just yet? You also seem to have included the `productDetailReducer` instead of the `productListReducer` that is the `productList` that your other code is selecting from. Well, I guess both are involved.

Comment: Yes it is still not resolved. I just now I added productList and ProductDetail actions and reducers code as well and  a json file screenshot which I am fetching productListing data.

Comment: @AmeyS Well, barring any response data issues I can certainly see that `state.productList.productListData.products` is undefined initially until the `setProductListData` action is dispatched with response data. In my opinion my answer and suggestion to fix the initial `state.productList.productListData` state value above is still valid. What is the value of `data` returned from `fetch("http://localhost:8000/productListing")` that is saved into state? Is it an object with matching `products` and `filters` keys?

Comment: It is an object with two arrays filters and products ->> { "productListing":{"filters:[]", "products:[]"} }

Comment: @AmeyS Ok, thank you for confirming, I just wanted to double check that the state was updated to a valid value your code is expecting. If you're not able to apply my answer's solution against your code, do you think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Hey @Drew Thank you so much for your help. I found out the issue and tried another solution and that worked for me. I fetched products data instead of using it from useSelector. I am answering that solution above. Please check and let me know that if this approach is correct.

Comment: I posted the answer. Please check if the approach is correct and please do comment. Thank you for your efforts. This worked for me. Now on refresh my selected product stays on the page.

Comment: @AmeyS Oh, I see, so you've just duplicated the fetch logic in both components? That's what I was trying to say to you with my comment about `setProductListData` a few comments back, that you needed to fetch data again. You could probably refactor that into a utility function that's imported into both, or if you have any asynchronous Redux middleware write a thunk and just dispatch the action to fetch the products data and populate state.

Comment: Okay. I am Sorry I didn't get your point before and I am fresher and in a learning phase. But is this what I have done is correct? Also please let me know for what purpose we use redux-thunk and redux-promise?

Comment: @AmeyS No worries at all. What you have seems to work, I was just saying you could make it more **DRY** (Don't Repeat Yourself) with a little refactoring. I don't know about `redux-promise`, but `redux-thunk` allows you to run asynchronous logic in an "action creator". If you happen to be using `redux-toolkit` then it has a thunk middleware already by default.

Comment: Ok. Now I got your point. Thank you so much Drew and keep up the good work.